# How to replace text in multiple locations of a sentence?

Tags: javascript, string, algorithm

I'm looking for an algorithm for changing a text in more than one location of a sentence.
For example, we have the next text:

***How much money has Rebecca Black made off of Friday?***

So, I have an object which holds 2 locations that need to be changed:

```
[{
    offset: 19,
    length: 13
}, {
    offset: 45,
    length: 6
}]
```

*Rebecca Black* and *Friday* need to be replaced with the same or different text... Let's say with **Treehouse**... doesn't really matter...

So my sentence should look like 
***How much money has *Treehouse* made off of *Treehouse*?***

The solution I have so far is to run backward and replace text one by one. It will ensure that positions were properly assigned, but it's a bit complicated way.

Any ideas?

Comment: I mean... offset 25 is not Friday? What am I not getting_

Comment: Do you know the exact words/phrases you want to change? In that case, `.replace` with regex will be helpful. Or do you only know the position and length of the areas in the string to change?

Comment: Is the offset of the second text (25) before or after the first one got replaced?

Comment: Er, 19/13 and 25/6 overlap! How do you resolve that?

Comment: Why can't you use a simple patch file like other tools, e.g. diff? https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diff_utility

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, you can `sort` the array by `offset` field, then just apply a function which **replace** with the desired `string`.

> Why sort ?

Because in this matter we can replace from `end` of the string to `start` of this string.

If not, then we could have follow problem: what is happened if we replace a **long** text with a **small** text ?

Then it's possible to have `offsets` which over exceeds the string length.

**Note:** that solution it's not guarantee that we will not have 
**overtaking** of given string(in case that offset exceeds the length of given string) but it's better `than` the solution without `sorting` the given **array**.

```js
let string='How much money has Rebecca Black made off of Friday?';

const replaceRange = (s, start, end, substitute) => s.substring(0, start) + substitute + s.substring(end);

let array=
[{
    offset: 19,
    length: 13
}, {
    offset: 40,
    length: 2
}];
array.sort(function(a,b){
  return b.offset-a.offset;
}).forEach(function(item){
    string=replaceRange(string,item.offset,item.offset+item.length,"XX");
});
console.log(string);
```

Comment: As you can see from running your code, it is buggy. It doesn't shift the offsets to account for the changed length of the string after replacement. That causes the "XX" to replace "f " instead of the word "Friday" in your result.

Comment: I would however replace with "X".repeat(offset.length) , then theres no need to sort at all...

Comment: Working perfectly. I've made a typo in Friday's offset... it should be 45 instead of 25. Tnx !!!

Answer (score 1):

```
var input = "How much money has Rebecca Black made off of Friday?";
var mask = [{
   offset: 19,
   length: 13
 }, {
   offset: 25,
   length: 6
}];

function replaceMask(input, mask){
  var result = "";
 for(var i = 0; i < input.length; i++){
  if(mask.find(rule => i > rule.offset && i < (rule.offset + rule.length))){
    result += "X";
  }else{
   result += input[i];
  }
 }
 return result;
}

console.log(replaceMask(input, mask));
```

[Try it](http://jsbin.com/rohokogilo/edit?console)

Answer (score 1):

Technically this does the trick, however your sample data overlaps. I just used different data to show it works.

```js
var data = "How much money has Rebecca Black made off of Friday?".split('');

replace = [{
  offset: 19,
  length: 13
}, {
  offset: 0,
  length: 3
}];

replace.forEach(function(el) {
      data.forEach(function(dataElement, index) {
          if (index >= el.offset && index < (el.offset + el.length))
           data[index] = "X";
          })
      })
data = data.join('');
console.log(data);
```